# Apache: how to unescape my client certificate?

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, client-certificates, openxpki

I have a configuration where I have nginx terminating https as reverse proxy, behind that an apache server that serves a perl application (openxpki).

That apache server needs to inject the client certificate into  `ENV:SSL_CLIENT_CERT` in order for openxpki to work.

nginx is configured to pass client certificate to apache via an http header `X-SSL-CERT`

```
    proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert;
```

Important to note that the certificate gets url encoded here by nginx. (otherwise it cannot be transferred in a header line)

Now apache needs to read the header and set it in ENV:SSL_CLIENT_CERT

Just using

```
    SetEnvIfNoCase X-SSL-CERT "(.*)" SSL_CLIENT_CERT=$1
```

wont work, as then you get the url encoded version in `ENV:SSL_CLIENT_CERT`

Using `unescape` is required here, to un-escape the url encoded cert.
I managed to get that working with

```
    # Cannot use unescape directly in SetEnvIfNoCase  as it only allows $1,$2, ..
    RequestHeader set X-SSL-CERT-UNESCAPED "expr=%{unescape:%{HTTP:X-SSL-CERT}}" early
    SetEnvIfNoCase X-SSL-CERT-UNESCAPED "(.*)" SSL_CLIENT_CERT=$1
```

This kinda works... however....

This unescaped everything, but forward slashes (%2F = '/'). As a certificate is base64 stuff, this does often contain forward slashes ->  leaving in %2F snippets, resulting in a broken cert in ENV:SSL_CLIENT_CERT

How can I get the certificate ('-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE...')   in my perl application?
How can I get apache to fully unescape this?

I tried all settings of `AllowEncodedSlashes`, but that didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Ok,  I have found the answer (workaround?) myself.

The following apache config makes it work

```
        RequestHeader set X-SSL-CERT-UNESCAPED "expr=%{unescape:%{HTTP:X-SSL-CERT}}" early
        # Fixing broken unescape() in apache config....
        # Replace the encoded forward slashes
        RequestHeader edit* X-SSL-CERT-UNESCAPED "%2F"  "/" early
        SetEnvIfNoCase X-SSL-CERT-UNESCAPED "(.*)" SSL_CLIENT_CERT=$1
```

Feels like working around apache bugs in config language though... (eg: using `early` is not recommended by apache: [`Early mode is designed as a test/debugging aid for developers`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html))

Using apache behind a reverse proxy seems common enough that there should be cleaner way to do this.

Does anyone know a clean(er) way to propagate a client certifcite from apache into your perl application?